# disable select form if radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, radio-button

How can I disable a select form dropdown if a radio button is selected?

I would like the #preference form to be disabled if the user selects the #no radio button and it to be enabled again if the user selects #yes or #maybe.

This is my form code -

```
<form name="xmas" id="xmas" action="send_mail.php" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Yes" id="yes"/><label for="yes">Yes - I would like to take up the offer</label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="No" id="no"/><label for="no">No - I'm not ready to order yet</label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Maybe" id="maybe"/><label for="maybe">Maybe - I'm not sure, would you please give me a call</label><br />
            <div class="secondlineform">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value=this.defaultValue){this.value=''}; return false;"/>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="textfield" value="Email" onfocus="if(this.value=this.defaultValue){this.value=''}; return false;"/>
                <input type="text" name="company" class="textfield" value="Company" onfocus="if(this.value=this.defaultValue){this.value=''}; return false;"/>
                <select class="dropselect" name="preference" label="Preference" id="preference">
                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="Preference">Preference</option>
                    <option value="Alcohol Package">Alcohol Package</option>
                    <option value="Gift Card Package">Gift Card Package</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit"/>

            </div>
        </form>
```

And this is my script code -

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

​

```
  var update_select = function () {
    if ($('#no').is(':checked')) {
    $('#preference').attr('disabled', "disabled");
}
else {
    $("#preference").removeAttr("disabled");
}

};

$(update_select);
$('#no').change(update_select);

</script>
```

Thanks very much for any answers! I've been researching this for ages and all the solutions I find don't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: Can't see where the error is... Try with `$('#preference').prop('disabled', true)` and then `('disabled', false)`

Comment: Sorry, but why you need to do this `$(update_select);`? update_select is a function, right?

Comment: Oh, actually there's something... why `
`$(update_select)` what's that supposed to do? Do you mean `update_select()`??

Answer (score 2):

you are adding change event for only `No` radio, change it to :

```
$("input[name='choice']").change(update_select);
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A57fE/5/)

Comment: I've tried all the answers on this forum and unfortunately none of them are working for me. I don't know script very well... Is there something I am missing? 

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
​
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var update_select = function () {
    
    if ($("#no").is(':checked')) {
    $("#preference").attr('disabled', "disabled");
    }
    else {
  
    $("#preference").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
 
    };
 
 
    $("input[name='choice']").change(update_select);​
    </script>

Comment: do you see any error in console...? did you see the demo link in jsfiddle..?

Comment: No errors in console and yes I saw the demo link. My code is exactly as yours but doesnt seem to work for me at all. I really appreciate your help. Thanks for responding so quickly and I'll keep working on it. There must be something small I'm missing. Perhaps I'm not referencing the jquery library properly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry! there was an error! SyntaxError: illegal character
[Break On This Error]  

$("input[name='choice']").change(update_select);​

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(update_select);​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `update_select` function to the rest of the radio button,like this

```
var update_select = function () {
$('#preference').attr('disabled', $('#no').is(':checked'));
};


$('#no').change(update_select);
$('#yes').change(update_select);
$('#maybe').change(update_select);
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QXkhM/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your radio button list by an ul and give it an ID.

For example:

```
        <ul id="offer">
        <input type="radio" name="choice"  value="Yes" id="yes"/><label for="yes">Yes - I would like to take up the offer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="choice"  value="No" id="no"/><label for="no">No - I'm not ready to order yet</label>
        <input type="radio" name="choice"  value="Maybe" id="maybe"/><label for="maybe">Maybe - I'm not sure, would you please give me a cal
        l</label><br />
        </ul>

var update_select = function () {
    if ($('#no').is(':checked')) {
        $('#preference').attr('disabled', "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("#preference").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
};
$(update_select);
$('#offer').change(update_select);
```

And it will work